# Join group on the js - SignalR 1.1.4

Tags: reactjs, signalr

I'm trying to join a group on the latest SignalR version and apparently it behaves different from the responses I could find.

Here's my hub:

```
public class NotificationsController : Hub
{
    public void Messages(string groupName, string message)
    {
        //I don't get this one
        Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Messages", $"from the group : {message}"); 

        // this one is fine
        Clients.All.SendAsync("Messages", message); 
    }
}
```

And here's my JS:

```js
    handleConnect(event) {
        const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/notifications")
            .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

        this.setState({ hubConnection, isConnected: true }, () => {
            this.state.hubConnection
                .start()
                .then(function() { 
                    console.log('Connection started!');
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

            this.state.hubConnection.on("Messages", (message) => {
                this.setState({ messages: this.state.messages.concat(message) });
            });

        });
    }
```

I'm not sure where to stick that I want to connect to the group X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by following [this tutorial](https://blog.elmah.io/building-a-cloud-editor-with-signalr-and-asp-net-core-2-1/)

in short:

Create a method to handle the groups:

```
    public async Task JoinGroup(string group)
    {
        if (connectionsNgroup.ContainsKey(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, connectionsNgroup[Context.ConnectionId]);
            connectionsNgroup.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        }
        connectionsNgroup.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }
```

and invoke the method after connecting:

```
this.state.hubConnection.invoke("JoinGroup", this.state.groupName).catch(err => console.error(err));
```